# How do I get rid of this amCharts distortion?

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I want to show my users ranking using the amCharts Javascript library. Users are ranked like this (It's good and with no problem) :

[image]

The problem is if I have two identical Profile names (for example if I have two Sara names as profile name or even two similar slogan sentences) something like this happens : (Here I changed John to Sara so we have two Saras)

Note: The whole text area goes down as arrows shown. and it seems I've lost one of those Saras ( Now I can see only 5 profiles instead of 6 profiles).

[image]

Plus I found [this code](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/) and [this one](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/handling-repeating-categories-on-category-axis/) in amCharts demos that seems to be a solution or a hint for this.

[Here is my code on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/pGMaQL?editors=1010)

And Here is my javascript code:

```
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end


var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
        "profileName": "John",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 6",
        "level": "6.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"

    }, {
        "profileName": "Sara",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 5",
        "level": "5.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Nima",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 4",
        "level": "4.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Max",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 3",
        "level": "3.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Megan",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 2",
        "level": "2.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Inna",
        "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 1",
        "level": "1.",
        "income": 0,
        "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }  ];

// Chart A:

//create category axis for Names Column 
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "profileName";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = -100;
categoryAxis.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.dy = -60;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.dx = 200;
categoryAxis.labelsEnabled = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 20;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#4286f4");


//create category axis for Slogans Column 
var categoryAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis2.dataFields.category = "slogan";
categoryAxis2.renderer.grid.template.location = 100;
categoryAxis2.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.dy = -20;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.dx = 200;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12;

//create category level
var categoryAxis3 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis3.dataFields.category = "level";
categoryAxis3.renderer.grid.template.location = 100;
categoryAxis3.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.dy = -20;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.dx = 170;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 16;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#ccd3e0");


//create value axis for income and expenses
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;



valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 10;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;  
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 25;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.disabled = true;

//create columns
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryY = "profileName";
series.dataFields.valueX = "income";
series.name = "Income";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;


// Do not crop bullets
chart.maskBullets = false;
chart.paddingTop = 64;
chart.paddingBottom = -30;

// Add bullets
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.width = 120;
image.height = 120;
image.dy = 0;
image.dx = 100;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet";
image.tooltipText = series.columns.template.tooltipText;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CategoryAxis` is a, well, a category axis. This means that items on your chart are grouped by "category", or `profileName` in your case.

If you have to identical categories (two Saras for example), they are grouped into a single slot, hence the issue you are having.

The only solution is to ensure all categories are unique. For example you can suffix each name with a `"~[userid]"`.

Then add an adapter which strips that suffix off:

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end


var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
        "profileName": "Sara~2",
  "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 6",
  "level": "6.",
        "income": 0,
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"

    }, {
        "profileName": "Sara",
  "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 5",
  "level": "5.",
        "income": 0,
  "bullet": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Nima",
  "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 4",
  "level": "4.",
        "income": 0,
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Max",
  "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 3",
  "level": "3.",
        "income": 0,
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Megan",
  "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 2",
  "level": "2.",
        "income": 0,
  "bullet": "https://i1.wp.com/teacupwellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Amanda-Blankinship-profile-circle.png?fit=300%2C300&ssl=1"
    }, {
        "profileName": "Inna",
  "slogan": "Slogan Sentence Related to Profile Name 1",
  "level": "1.",
        "income": 0,
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png"
    }  ];
 
// Chart A:

//create category axis for Names Column 
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "profileName";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = -100;
categoryAxis.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.dy = -60;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.dx = 200;
categoryAxis.labelsEnabled = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 20;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#4286f4");
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("textOutput", stripSuffix);


//create category axis for Slogans Column 
var categoryAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis2.dataFields.category = "slogan";
categoryAxis2.renderer.grid.template.location = 100;
categoryAxis2.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.dy = -20;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.dx = 200;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("textOutput", stripSuffix);

//create category level
var categoryAxis3 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis3.dataFields.category = "level";
categoryAxis3.renderer.grid.template.location = 100;
categoryAxis3.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.dy = -20;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.dx = 170;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 16;
categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#ccd3e0");

function stripSuffix(category) {
  return category.split("~").shift();
}


//create value axis for income and expenses
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;



valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 10;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;  
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 25;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.disabled = true;

//create columns
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryY = "profileName";
series.dataFields.valueX = "income";
series.name = "Income";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;


// Do not crop bullets
chart.maskBullets = false;
chart.paddingTop = 64;
chart.paddingBottom = -30;

// Add bullets
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.width = 120;
image.height = 120;
image.dy = 0;
image.dx = 100;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet";
image.tooltipText = series.columns.template.tooltipText;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 840px;
}

body { 
 margin: 40 100 100 20;
 background-color: transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff); 
 }
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```